# How to refresh a single thumbnail in Files (Loki) without deleting the thumbnail cash?

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files

When I make changes to an image, I still see the old thumbnail of the old image in Files. Is there a way to refresh a single thumbnail without deleting thumbnail cash? Sometimes the thumbnail refreshes automatically, other times F5 works, but not all the time. Or it refreshes if I rename the file, but that's expected anyway. In Ubuntu I was using a script for Nautilus.